# ingresar los datos de un formulario a phpmyadmin usando javascript, ajax y php (no puedo usar jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmyadmin

Necesito ingresar los datos de un formulario a phpmyadmin usando javascript, ajax y php (no puedo usar jquery), el servidor me recibe los datos y el estado sale que está "ok", por lo que creo que no hay problema en esa parte.

Mi sentencia en el archivo procesar.php es esta:
Si es necesario puedo enviar la carpeta con el resto de archivos por otro medio, ya que no sé hacerlo por acá

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO curriculum (TIP_IDENTIFICACION,NUM_IDENTIFICACION,DSC_NOMBRE,DSC_APELLIDOS,IND_SEXO,FEC_NACIMIENTO,DSC_LUGAR,DSC_NACIONALIDAD,IND_ESTADO,DSC_TELEFONO,DSC_EMAIL,DSC_DOMICILIO,IND_PROVINCIA)
    VALUES(
    '".$tipoIdentificacion."',
    ".$_REQUEST["ide"].",
    '".$_REQUEST["nombre"]."', 
    '".$_REQUEST["apellidos"]."',
    '".$_REQUEST["rd_sexo"]."',
    '".$_REQUEST["fechaNacimiento"]."', 
    '".$_REQUEST["lugarNac"]."',
    '".$_REQUEST["nacionalidad"]."',
    '".$estadoC."',
    ".$_REQUEST["tel"].",
    '".$_REQUEST["email"]."' ,
    '".$_REQUEST["domicilio"]."' ,
    '".$provincia."'
    )";
?>
```

Comment: Estimado, no añadas **resuelto** en el título de tu pregunta, si se resolvió tu problema, verifica la respuesta que te sirvió marcándolo al ✔️, saludos.

Comment: Déjanos saber si alguna de las respuestas o comentarios solucionó tu problema marcándola con el check y con el upvote del lado izquierdo. En caso contrario, deja un comentario para tratar de darte otras soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que estás tratando de acceder de manera incorrecta a los datos que llegan del formulario, ya que la variable reservada (y superglobal) `$_REQUEST`, según [la documentación oficial de `PHP`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php) es

> Un array asociativo que por defecto contiene el contenido de $_GET, $_POST y $_COOKIE.

En su lugar, puedes acceder a los datos que te llegan del formulario a través de los métodos `$_GET` o `$_POST`, dependiendo de como esté configurado tu proyecto.

Puedes revisar cómo te llegan los datos usando la función `var_dump($_POST);` o `print_r($_POST);`.

Por cierto, `phpMyAdmin` es solo un administrador, realmente tu motor de base de datos debe ser `mySql` o `mariaDB`.